# Sugar bean not populated in Controller method in Sugar CRM 6.5

Tags: jquery, soap, sugarcrm

I am trying to add the following functionality to a SugarCRM detail page:

1. When a button is clicked, a popup is displayed with a list of values loaded from an external service. The user can then manipulate the contents of the popup.
2. When "Submit" is clicked on the popup, the record (bean) is updated with this changed data.

So far I've managed to add a button (I discuss it in this question [Adding a button with custom JavaScript in SugarCRM 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142652/adding-a-button-with-custom-javascript-in-sugarcrm-6-5/59151447?noredirect=1#comment104545247_59151447)) the usual Sugar way by adding it to detailviewdefs.php.

But instead of the button having a 'soap' field in its definition, `'soap' => 'CaseButtons/Approve'` I hooked up a JavaScript function to the button which does a jQuery ajax call and displays a popup.

Creating a random php file in my SugarCRM structure and then trying to call it would end up in 403 Forbidden. But I did manage to call a function I made in the controller class:

```
$ajax( { url: "?module=Cases&action=GetQuestions" ...
```

I was able to pass parameters and get a response to this call. All seemed well.

Then I noticed in the debugger, that the `$this->bean` property is not populated in my function. The object is set, but except for `field_key` (which is set to some guid) no other fields contain a value (all nulls or empty arrays) including the id. I have checked existing functions, and the fields in the bean are populated.

For my first call which gathers the information this is not a problem, but for the second call that is supposed to save the bean this is a huge problem.

I realize this is probably caused by me not using the standard 'soap' way to access the controller. But I can't imagine how I could create a popup with custom data and behavior that way.

Is there a way to make sure the bean is loaded when my function runs? Can I perhaps load it manually? I have the bean's id at my disposal (I send it from the UI). Would this break the normal Sugar functionality regarding saving beans (pre-, post-save hooks etc)

Or is there a way I can call the Sugar SOAP from JavaScript? I was thinking the "Submit" button could call the SOAP (since it's the only one that really needs it).

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an id to your action you can use

```
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Cases', $id);
```

to load the Case with the id $id manually.

This won't impact logic_hooks the ->save() method will still trigger those

Comment: Thanks. I have solved this already, I could have sworn I answered the topic with my solution :/. Turns out if you put record=[record id] in the request payload, the Sugar middleware will load the bean in the background before the controller function is hit.