# Javascript difference between document.write and DOM element.AppendChild(text)

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to embed and show a flash file. It works fine with document.write but when I tried with AppendChild(text) it doesn't show flash but pure text instead. What DOM method to use instead ?

```
  <html>
  <head>
 <script>
  function addText(text,elementId){
    if (document.createTextNode){
      var mytextNode=document.createTextNode(text)
      document.getElementById(elementId).appendChild(mytextNode)
    }
  }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

                <div id="test">

                </div>

  <script>
      addText("<embed height='100' width='100' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' wmode='transparent' quality='high' swliveconnect='true' name='test' id='test' src='test.swf'>",'test');
  </script>     
  </body></html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `.innerHTML`?

Comment: I think you want document.createElement() instead.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367214/document-write-vs-inserting-dom-nodes-preserve-form-information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var myEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
    myEmbed.type="application/x-shockwave-flash";
    myEmbed.height='100';
    myEmbed.width='100';
    …
    document.getElementById("test").appendChild(myEmbed);
}());
```

At first glance such an approach can often seem unnecessarily noisy and worthless, but it integrates much more sanely with the natural syntax of HTML. If you want to be able to write HTML directly into your document, you might be happier with a framework like jQuery, which allows syntax like:

```
$("<embed src='…'/>")
```

However, if you're just doing all this to embed Flash, use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Comment: Both answers are good, I attributed to you because you have less points ;)

Comment: LOL, that's a funny reason. I'll give @alex a +1 to help keep things balanced. :P

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating a text node, not serialised HTML.

You could change the function to...

```
function addHTML(html, elementId) {
    if (document.createElement) {

        var holder = document.createElement('div');

        holder.innerHTML = html;

        var target = document.getElementById(elementId);

        while (holder.hasChildNodes()) {
            target.appendChild(holder.firstChild);
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNTkg/).

Comment: Thank you very much it's unfortunate one cannot check 2 good answers.